# How to lock user out from using OS on Ubuntu MATE (Raspberry Pi 3)

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm building a Tkinter GUI in Python 3.7 meant to run on a Raspberry Pi 3, and I want the user to be unable to close it or access the OS (Ubuntu MATE) below it.

I tried using this flag to make the window un-closeable:

```py
root.overrideredirect(boolean=True)
```

but this creates all top-level widgets underneath the root window. I tried forcing them to be created above the root using a variety of different methods but with no luck.

I then tried to update idle tasks before setting the flag:

```py
root.update_idletasks()
root.overrideredirect(boolean=True)
```

and this worked on my Intel desktop running Ubuntu, but when running it on a Raspberry Pi 3 running Ubuntu MATE, updating idle tasks before setting the flag just seems to have disabled it completely, meaning the user could still access the OS.

I was wondering how could I prevent the user from accessing the OS on the Raspberry Pi 3. Any help would be nice.